# jQuery tabs width

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs, width

I'm using the standard default functionality for jQuery tabs and I have them up and running but am having difficulties styling them.

I've tried overwriting where I think the styles are coming from but to no avail (I've removed those attempts from my code to avoid confusion - left the margin and padding to 0 for everything though). I'd like the A-Z tabs to all fit on one 'line' ideally (whilst still retaining the `500px` width of `#main`).

Can anyone point me in the right direction with what I need to do, or even better provide me with the CSS that will get what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/Deva/eTx5x/

Comment: excuse me, what do you mean with "I'd like the A-Z tabs to all fit on one 'line' ideally.". do you want to make all tabs(a-z) in one line? if the answer is 'yes', you can set the #main width to 1350px (before it was 500px)

Comment: yes - correct, except i want to keep the main width at 500px. sorry i should have been more clear :)

Comment: You want them on one line but you want the width to stay at 500px? So you want the tabs to be smaller? :p

Comment: yes precisely. i want the tabs to be smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your css

```
div#tabs ul li, div#tabs ul li a {
  width: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eTx5x/21/

Comment: This solution does not function with jQuery Tools v1.2.7